# How do I copy files from a Unix server to a Windows client with SSH?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, file-transfer

I have connected to a Unix server using SSH from my terminal from my Windows client.

How do I copy files from the Unix server to the Windows client? Can I use the scp and rcp commands? Or are there other ways to do so?

Comment: I think it belongs to superuser.com

Comment: congrats on the baby windows client!

Comment: @Dan: ?????? I didn't got it.

Comment: "But i am having a windows client" as in "But i am having a baby". Crikey, humor shouldn't need to be explained :-)

Comment: @pax & dan: sorry arf that's a good joke! but I am not native English speaker so kind of difficult to get that kind of joke!

Comment: snif I didn't got any drop of reputation on that ^^ pax you rule them all...

Comment: I've never seen a joke work on any stack* site, darn it. I've tried.

Comment: But we can still keep trying, can't we?

Comment: keep trying, @pavium... just use protection or you may end up with a windows client...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying files with SSH](http://superuser.com/questions/92233/copying-files-with-ssh)

Answer (score 10):

`scp` is the way that we do this. If you're using something like putty, it comes with `pscp` as part of it.

I prefer `pscp` over the standard `scp` since it allows you to specify a password on the command line, something useful for scripting.

An example invocation from one of my scripts (details changed to protect the innocent):

```
pscp -pw paxpwd src.tar.gz pax@pax.com:/usr/pax/tmp/src.tar.gz
```

This copies the `src.tar.gz` file from my local (Windows) directory to `/usr/pax/tmp` on my `pax.com` UNIX machine, using the `pax/paxpwd` user and password.

Your particular use case would be satisfied by:

```
pscp -pw biranchipwd biranchi@myunixserver.com:abc/xyz.txt xyz.txt
```

Keep in mind that placing passwords into scripts is not generally a good idea since it means anyone that breaks into your local machine can easily break into the other machine as well.

Comment: i accept your answer, can u please write the syntax for it.
Say i have a file xyz.txt in my unix server under abc folder.I want to copy it to my windows desktop.

Comment: @biranchi: you do the reverse from your windows machice get/put whatever file. It won't be possible to copy from your unix box, since your windows box doesn't have a ssh server.

Comment: @Biranchi, see the update for a sample command on the Windows side. @RageZ, if you install Cygwin, there's an ssh deomon that you can run but I'd still suggest just using the client on Windows and server on UNIX.

Comment: @pax; you are right you can run sshd on windows but more easy to use the unix server since it's already there ^^

Comment: @RageZ: I am using putty to ssh to my unix server.

Answer (score 2):

you should check [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol). [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is able to handle SFTP session. also putty provide a [pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp directly on the command prompt itself: For example:

> c:>scp myuser@myhost.com:/home/myuser/test.properties .
>
> myuser@myhost.com's password:
>
> test.properties                            100%   675     0.7KB/s   00:00

Comment: @techzen: did you read his question ? last time I checked there was no scp command on the windows distro ...

Comment: Eek! And s?he's writing to the root of the C: drive. Where you shouldn't even have write permissions, usually. That'd be, like, telling UNIX users to download files somewhere to /

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WinSCP](http://winscp.net) for a free GUI SFTP client if you don't want to bother with the command line.