# How can I copy files with SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, cp

I am trying to copy a file from my other computer, to another computer. (both running Ubuntu 9.10)

So, I've ssh'ed into the other computer; I `cd` to the directory; and I entered `cp File.zip /home/me/Desktop` as `file.zip` is located in the directory I just used `cd` with.

Now, it gives me the following error message:

`cannot create regular file '/home/me/Desktop': no such file or directory`

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This isn't really programming related, but you can use scp to do this.

```
scp file.zip remote-box-name:/path/to/destination/file.zip
```

If your username is different on the remote box, you will need to prefix it:

```
scp file.zip yourusername@remotebox:/path/to/destination/file.zip
```

And to retrieve a file you could do this:

```
scp remotebox:/path/to/destination/file.zip file.zip
```

Comment: how does that work when i am sshed into the other computer on the computer where i want to copy the file to? Because when i try like `scp file.zip me@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/home/me/Desktop`, it says 'connection refused', probably because it is the computer im on. How to?

Comment: The syntax is `src_file dest_file`, where either can be just a filename on a local computer (file.zip), or a remote file (me@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/home/me/Desktop).  So if you want to _pull_ a files from a remote machine to the local machine, you would do `scp xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/home/me/Desktop/file.zip file.zip`.

Note that local and remote are relative to the machine you are running the scp.  So if you are on machine A, ssh to machine B and do an scp, B is local and A is remote.

Comment: It still gives the same error as i shown in the question

Comment: when i try to do it from local machine, it says 'no route to host' or something like that... probably because it is protected with a password.

Comment: sftp is another good option if you're comfortable with ftp and are doing this manually.

Comment: @TutorialPoint: 'no route to host' indicates you have a general networking problem, not an scp problem.  Try http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/no-route-to-host-error-and-solution.html

Comment: can we retrieve multiple files?

Answer (score 8):

1. On machine A, open two terminal windows
2. On machine A, ssh to machine B. Look around, find the path on machine B to the file you wish to copy
3. On machine A, the second terminal window type:

`scp yourusername@remotebox:/path/to/destination/file.zip /home/me/Desktop`

The file should be copied from machine B to machine A, in to the /home/me/Desktop folder (if the folder exists on Machine A

You can't copy over the existing ssh session. You need to create a second session. As others have noted:

- `yourusername` is for Machine B, and is only needed if the username for Machine B is different than on Machine A
- `remotebox` can be a resolvable name or an IP address

**Alternatives:**

- *Places -> Connect to Server*, and then select *Service Type* of **SSH** from the pulldown menu of the *Connect to Server* dialog box

Comment: if i want to copy a folder ? how

Answer (score 0):

try the following command:

`scp File.zip username@AnotherComputer:~/`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use scp to either pull or push the file. From one machine to the other, you'd do something like

`scp File.zip username@ipaddress:/home/me/Desktop/file.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Mount remote machine locally with `sshfs` and copy files with your favorite tool- cp, nautilus, konqueror, dolphin, mc etc.

or use `fish://username@servername` in konqueror or dolphi top open the remote location